# Binding selectand preventing a user selection certain options

Tags: knockout.js

```
<select data-bind="options: vm.BusinessStatus, optionsText: 'vcrStatus', optionsValue: 'intStatusID', value: CurrentStatus ">

vm.CurrentStatus.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    alert("the new value is " + newValue);
});

   self.BusinessStatus = ko.observableArray([{ "intStatusID": "2", "vcrStatus": "Provis" }, { "intStatusID": "1", "vcrStatus": "Active" }, { "intStatusID": "3", "vcrStatus": "Negative" }, { "intStatusID": "4", "vcrStatus": "Active (Verified)" }])
```

When the page loads and the select is being populated the event the alert will fire for each option untile it finally binds to the value. I wish to fire off an event if the user changes the current status to another status, and also restrict the user from selecting a status on the ui but not stop the dropdown from binding to this status if thats what is in the database. I have added the options as a Data will eventually come from a database but is currently as is in the example.

Comment: Here, I've created jsfiddle from your code- http://jsfiddle.net/o5c7msav/. What do you mean by - "I wish to fire off an event if the **user changes the current status** to another status, and also **restrict the user from selecting a status** on the ui" - how would the user change the status if you want to restrict him from doing that?

Comment: when the page loads the status will bind to the value that comes from the database, could be any one of 4 status, this database is populated from another process. In the UI the user can select any of the 4 status but if it is a disallowed status, they will get a message saying that this status is not allowed and the status will return to its original. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `beforeChange` option of KO subscription logic (see [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html)).

Suppose your view model looks something like this:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.availableStatuses = ko.observableArray(["New", "In progress", "Fixed", "Verified"]);
    self.currentStatus = ko.observable("New");
    self.oldStatus = self.currentStatus();
    self.currentStatus.subscribe(function(oldValue) {
        self.oldStatus = oldValue ;
    }, null, 'beforeChange');
    self.currentStatus.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        if (newValue != "New" && newValue != "In progress") {
            alert("Value " + newValue + " is not allowed!");
            self.currentStatus(self.oldStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

Where `availableStatuses` contains array of your available statuses from the database, `currentStatus` is an observable with currently selected status. You also can see 2 subscriptions here, first one is fired before `currentStatus` is changed to remember its value and the second one fires after the change, makes validations and sets the value accordingly.

Markup looks like this:

```
<select data-bind="options: availableStatuses, value: currentStatus"></select>
```

Here is working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Lffymbb/1/).

**Edit:**

To postpone subscriptions until the moment the data is loaded you can do something like this:

```
ViewModel.prototype.init = function() {
    var self = this;
    // Let's assume that we made an ajax call to server to get data and in success callback
    // we populate the data and adding subscriptions.
    self.availableStatuses(["New", "In progress", "Fixed", "Verified"]);
    self.currentStatus(self.availableStatuses()[0]);
    // make subscriptions
    self.currentStatus.subscribe(function(oldValue) {
        self.oldStatus = oldValue ;
    }, null, 'beforeChange');
    self.currentStatus.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        if (newValue != "New" && newValue != "In progress") {
            alert("Value " + newValue + " is not allowed!");
            self.currentStatus(self.oldStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

See updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Lffymbb/2/). You also may find useful the `dispose()` method (see [Explicitly subscribing to observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html)) that can be applied to subscription (for example, when you need to reload your available statuses, you can dispose currentStatus subscriptions and add new ones after loading is complete.

Comment: Hi, how would I prevent this happening when the page loads, it seem sto give alerts when the data is loading into the select, thanks

Comment: @user2332277 It won't fire on page loading unless you're making subscriptions before the actual data is loaded from server. I've added possible solution for postponed subscriptions. If it works, you can voteup my answer :)